# AS3 FileReference Download Doesn't Work in IE/FF (Works fine in Chrome)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, filereference

I am generating an Excel file with Java on the back-end and it seems to work just fine in Chrome but for whatever reason it doesn't in FF/IE. I have the very latest of Flash in each browser listed from this site: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html

I'm sending XML to the server, it is generating the Excel and sending it to the Flash. I'm performing the export by doing the following:

```
private var _fileRef:FileReference;

private function exportReport(e:MouseEvent):void
{       
    _fileRef = new FileReference();
    _fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, excelExportCompleteHandler);
    _fileRef.download(new URLRequest("exportReport"), "report.xlsx");

    function excelExportCompleteHandler(e:Event):void {
        trace('complete');
    }
}
```

I tried every possible error and handler on it but nothing fails so I put a breakpoint in the complete handler and noticed there is an I/O error just it's not happening on the IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR handler.

Left hand side is a successful download, right hand side is a failure.

[image: Left side successful, right side failure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on Adobe's forum and came up with my own workaround. It's not ideal but for others interested: http://forums.adobe.com/message/4983605

Comment: Did you ever get any further with diagnosing this, or did you just go with your workaround and sigh? I am having the same issue, also with xlsx. Again the IOErrorEvent handler is not being triggered, but the try{} block catches an IOError for me. I'm uploading the xlsx (browsed to) and then pulling it in to the swf to be parsed as xml. I wondered if IE/FF simply block some activity around .xlsx files? What is particularly puzzling in our case is that many IE users are fine, but others are not. The webserver logs don't even show an attempt.